# Organize list numerically instead of alphabetically

Tags: php, sorting, glob

I have a bunch of folders like this:

```
Letter#1
Letter#10
Letter#2
Letter#3
```

How can I re-order them so that when I read them in using `glob` I get:

```
Letter#1
Letter#2
Letter#3
Letter#10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to get it ordered.

1. You can just remove the string `Letter#` and then order it like this.

```
$folders = ['Letter#1', 'Letter#2', 'Letter#3', 'Letter#10']; 
$prefix = 'Letter#';

foreach ($folders as $key => $folder) {
    $folders[$key] = ltrim($folder, $prefix); 
}

$folder = sort($folders, SORT_NUMERIC);

foreach ($folders as $key => $folder) {
    $folders[$key] = $prefix . $folder; 
}

print_r($folders);
```